# Depth and OOB error of a randomForest and randomForestSRC

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, random-forest

Here is my code for random forest and rfsrc in R; Is there anyway to include  n_estimators and  max_depth like sklearn version in my R code ? Also, How can I plot OBB error vs number of trees plot like this?

[image]

```
set.seed(2234)
tic("Time to train RFSRC fast")
fast.o <- rfsrc.fast(Label ~ ., data = train[(1:50000),],forest=TRUE)
toc()
print(fast.o)

#print(vimp(fast.o)$importance)

set.seed(2367)
tic("Time to test RFSRC fast ")
#data(breast, package = "randomForestSRC")
fast.pred <- predict(fast.o, test[(1:50000),])
toc()
print(fast.pred)


set.seed(3)
tic("RF model fitting without Parallelization")
rf <-randomForest(Label~.,data=train[(1:50000),])
toc()
print(rf)
plot(rf)
varImp(rf,sort = T)
varImpPlot(rf, sort=T, n.var= 10, main= "Variable Importance", pch=16)

rf_pred <- predict(rf, newdata=test[(1:50000),])
confMatrix <- confusionMatrix(rf_pred,test[(1:50000),]$Label)
confMatrix
```

I appreciate your time.

Comment: This is not a programming forum, so I fear your question is off topic. What sklearn calls `n_estimators` is called `ntree`. rfsrc has a `nodedepth` parameter to control the depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `block.size=1` , and also take note the sampling is without replacement, you can check the vignette for rfsrc:

> Unlike Breiman's random forests, the default action here is sampling
>   without replacement.  Thus out-of-bag (OOB) technically means
>   out-of-sample, but for legacy reasons we retain the term OOB.

So using an example dataset,

```
library(mlbench)
library(randomForestSRC)
data(Sonar)
set.seed(911)
trn = sample(nrow(Sonar),150)
rf <- rfsrc(Class ~ ., data = Sonar[trn,],ntree=500,block.size=1,importance=TRUE)
pred <- predict(rf,Sonar[-trn,],block.size=1)
plot(rf$err.rate[,1],type="l",col="steelblue",xlab="ntrees",ylab="err.rate",
ylim=c(0,0.5))
lines(pred$err.rate[,1],col="orange")
legend("topright",fill=c("steelblue","orange"),c("test","OOB.train"))
```

[image]

In randomForest:

```
library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(Class ~ ., data = Sonar[trn,],ntree=500)
pred <- predict(rf,Sonar[-trn,],predict.all=TRUE)
```

Not very sure if there's an easier to get ntrees error:

```
err_by_tree = sapply(1:ncol(pred$individual),function(i){
apply(pred$individual[,1:i,drop=FALSE],1,
function(i)with(rle(i),values[which.max(lengths)]))
})

err_by_tree = colMeans(err_by_tree!=Sonar$Class[-trn])
```

Then plot:

```
plot(rf$err.rate[,1],type="l",col="steelblue",xlab="ntrees",ylab="err.rate",
    ylim=c(0,0.5))
    lines(err_by_tree,col="orange")
    legend("topright",fill=c("steelblue","orange"),c("test","OOB.train"))
```

[image]

Comment: cool. if it works for you :) you can also consider accepting https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer, to indicate it solved your problem and will be helpful for others

Comment: Sure! I will do it. However, I have a quick question. If i want to plot the graphs for larger sample say, 5000+, It is not working. My sample size is 754590. How can I plot for large samples? It worked well for 500 samples!

Comment: Ok so for the code above, you are taking it for increments of 1 tree. So for src, you do block.size=10 or 20 .. then take out the rf$err.rate matrix, and subset the non NAs.. This should be easily do-able

Comment: For randomForest, instead of ```1:ncol(pred$individual) ,  you would so seq(1,ncol(pred$individual), by=20) ```for example

Comment: Hopefully this gives you less points to calculate and then you can plot it. Again I do not your data, I can only guess what is the obstacle you have. Also if it is a programming issue you face now, might be better to post it as a separate question on stackoverflow

Comment: I am trying to extract overall.err.ratee from the above rfsrc. It is showing me nan value. Is there any way to extract this info from rf <- rfsrc(Class ~ ., data = Sonar[trn,],ntree=500,block.size=1,importance=TRUE) model? I appreciate your time. Thanks!